# How to use Selenium WebDriver on local webpage (on my PC) instead of one located somewhere online?

Tags: java, url, path, selenium-webdriver

I want to use Selenium WebDriver on a webpage that I have on my hard disc. I've tried to something like:

```java
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "C:\\...dispatcher.html");
```

...instead of the normal:

```java
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.dunnowhattodo.org");
```

...but it doesn't work (I get the error "unknown protocol: c").

Comment: It may require the `file://` protocol before it...have you tried that?

Comment: no i haven't tried it: file://C://... should it be this way?

Comment: @ Bartosz Wygledacz: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3997

Comment: Already answered above, but how I did: java.io.File localPage = new File("C:/debug/mypage.html");
webdriver.get(localPage.getPath());

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try using this method:

```
webdriver.get("file:///D:/folder/abcd.html");
```

(or)

```
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "file:///D:/folder/abcd.html");
```

Comment: Can relative paths be used somehow?

Comment: @Pithikos no, but when using windows you can use the environment variables, like %USERPROFILE% (home folder) and %APPDATA% (application folder)

Comment: How do you do this on macOS with Safari? I can't open html files from the local file system.
It's working if I use file:///Users/pathToMyFile/index.html manually in the browser. However it's not working if the driver opens it by the get method.

Comment: It worked on my aws instance :)

Answer (score 6):

This can also be done with a relative file:

```
Path sampleFile = Paths.get("sample.html");
driver.get(sampleFile.toUri().toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can always drag and drop html file from your PC on open web browser during selenium session and see how file path looks. In my case it is:

```
webdriver.get("file:///C:/Users/Desktop/Some%20%E2%80%93%20file%20on%20the%20PC.html")
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call the driver.get(URL) method, WebDriver looks for HTTP request using as base javascript, Therefore, refering to a website as a path, that task won't be possible.

But it will be possible if you :
1st- Install Apache WebServer (let's say) on your marchine.
2nd- Upload or expose to the WebServer, that web application (dispatcher.html)
3rd- Try recording and executing your testcases on [http://localhost:8080/dispatcher.html]    (8080 is the default port but you can configure it to other).

Answer (score 2):

For those of us using `java.nio`, we can also do the following:

```
webdriver.get("file:\\\\\\" + filePath);
```

...where `filePath` is an object of type `java.nio.file.Path` and represents an *absolute* path.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium Version: 3.141.59

Use this webdriver.get("file:///D:/folder/abcd.html") get failed.

Instead of webdriver.get("///D:/folder/abcd.html") get successfully.