# Loading local resource with WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

New to Selenium WebDriver, and I'm wondering if it is possible to retrieve a WebElement representing a local resource - ie. an HTML file found in my classpath.

I am trying to write a unit test, and this seems a bit more prudent compared to attempting to mock out a WebDriver and somehow injecting my target web page content.

Comment: This is answered here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972885/how-to-use-selenium-webdriver-on-local-on-my-pc-webpage-instead-of-locate-somw

Comment: So, I'd have to get a resource URL? Would it work for resources in jars?