# How to open a link in Selenium which is saved in desktop

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to read email from DB and save that email as .html on my desktop and then open that html and go through docusign process to complete the process.

I have code written for reading from DB and saving the output file as .html in my documents.

Now, I want to open that file in a new webdriver session and continue with rest of my testing. How can I achieve that?

We are using Selenium Python. Please advise

Comment: Are you asking about opening a local html file with webdriver? If yes, this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972885/how-to-use-selenium-webdriver-on-local-on-my-pc-webpage-instead-of-locate-somw.

Comment: Thank you man! It worked... I also have a question on copy and paste code. Do i need to open a  new thread or Can i post it here?

Comment: I think the right move would be to close this thread as a duplicate. Or, if you don't agree this is a duplicate - consider providing your own solution as an answer and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
webdriver.get("file:///D:/folder/abcd.html");
```

(or)

```
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "file:///D:/folder/abcd.html");
```