# It's possible to do an XHR call and render the output with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver

Well, the title says it all... It is possible to perform an XmlHttpRequest from Selenium/Webdriver and then render the output of that requests in a browser instance ? If so, can you enlight me please ?

Comment: Could you please describe the use case and motivation behind the question?

Comment: In tumblr, when you search for posts, the page has infinite scrolling. It issues an XHR to fetch more posts... having the page loaded, the xhr should automatically update the current page ???

Comment: You can approach it by simulating that infinite scrolling with python+selenium.

Comment: I know that I can scroll the page, but I would like to do it using http requests...

Comment: Then, you just don't need selenium. Use `requests` package, or even better - the tumblr api, https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to make the XHR request using, for instance, [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), save the response to a file and `get()` it with selenium webdriver instance ([How to use selenium webdriver on local (on my pc) webpage instead of locate somwhere on www?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972885/how-to-use-selenium-webdriver-on-local-on-my-pc-webpage-instead-of-locate-somw)).

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is really designed to be an external *control system* for a web browser.  I don't think of it as being the **source** of test data, itself.  There are other unit-testing frameworks which are designed for this purpose, but I see *Selenium's* intended purpose to be different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
fileupload_url = 'https://this-site.com/upload'
filedata = open('example.txt').read()
ajax_request = '''
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream'); // text/plain
xhr.onload = function(){{  document.body.innerHTML += '<div>Passed!</div>';
                          alert (xhr.responseText); }} // success case
xhr.onerror = function(){{ document.body.innerHTML += '<div>Failed!</div>';
                          alert (xhr.responseText); }} // failure case
xhr.open ('POST', {}, true);
xhr.send ({});
'''.format(fileupload_url, filedata)
driver.execute_script(ajax_request)
```