# Selenium Web Driver With HTML Input Source

Tags: selenium-webdriver

If you are using Selenium in Java and have a string of HTML and JavaScript Source are you able to have a real browser render the source with the webdriver?

Comment: try it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17973306/2517622

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can open the HTML file in a browser. You have to specify the "`file:///`" protocol in `get()` method to open the file in browser. You can refer below code.

```
webdriver.get("file:///<filePath>/fileName.html");
```

Do let us know if that helps you out.