# Load html file from project folder

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do i load a html file in webdriver from the src/test/resources folder, like

driver.get("file///src//resources//test//login.html")
This is giving me invalid argument error..
I want the code to run in any system without any dependency on folder structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Selenium WebDriver on local webpage (on my PC) instead of one located somewhere online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972885/how-to-use-selenium-webdriver-on-local-webpage-on-my-pc-instead-of-one-located)

Answer (score -1):

`driver.get()` method expect http or https protocol to be inject on the browser. when you try with file path it wont work.

What exactly you want to achieve/ Can you please elaborate?